# Which filter is better and faster

Tags: python, django

I am relatively new to django and python, so i would really like to know which of these two implementation is the better or faster approach. I am currently using the filter, but i thought of it, and cos i really like list comprehension, i wrote the same code using list comprehension. Both codes do exactly the same thing, but I just want to know from developers with more experience which is better and why. Below are both codes.

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(approved=True).order_by('-date_posted')

posts = [post for post in Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted') if post.approved]
```

Comment: The first one filters at the database level, hence the database will never return all these records. A database can also have indexes, etc. making filtering even faster. If you can move work to the database, then this is usually better, since databases are optimized to do efficient filtering, ordering, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @WillemVanOnsem. I actually had a feeling it would be faster, and I am actually using it instead of the one with list comprehension cos it filters and only gives you what you asked for directly and not looking through all of them before filtering. I just really like how the list comprehension one looks, and just wanted a professional opinion. Thanks for giving me that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `.filter(..)` is *not* implemented to performed filtering on the Django/Python level: filtering is done on the database, with a `WHERE` (or `HAVING`) clause. Databases are systems that are designed to store, retrieve, and aggregate large amounts of data.

If you often filter on the `approved` value, you can add an index on the column:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    approved = models.BooleanField(db_index=True)
```

In that case, the database will add an indexing structure that make filtering more efficient.

It is usually better to filter on the database, since that means the database needs to communicate fewer records to the Python/Django layer, and furthermore Django has to *deserialize* fewer objects into memory objects. So even if filtering with a list comprehension were as fast as filtering through the database, it would still be less efficient, because Python/Django would first have to deserialize more elements. If the number of elements is growing, it will eventually result in memory problems, since you won't be able to store all the records at the same time in memory.

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually would add db_index to the column.